# How to make an element in CSS with a truly fixed size?

Tags: css, size

I'm currently trying to make a responsive navbar (and it works, is responsive), but at some window size, it becomes too big. So I tried to use `@media (max-width)` to block its growth at some point. Unfortunately, when I use `px` to describe new fixed size, the navbar is now affected by scaling of the page (ctrl+mouse wheel), and I'm trying to avoid this behavior.

Is there a workaround to my problem?

Comment: Please post your code, snippet, or link s owe can look at what you've done.

Answer (score -1):

Little hard to understand your question, but any good navbar should scale width wise for a page. I kinda sounds like you set the height style to a percentage rather than pixel amount.

```
<div style='height:80px;width:100%;'>Content</div>
```

This makes a horizontally scaling bar, with a constant heigjht